# merge two textArea into one with specific order

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtextarea

I use these Arrays to get the text from the textArea

```
array1 = textArea1.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
array2 = textArea2.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
```

I want to combine both of them in a specific way and show the result in a `textArea3`. For example I want to take the first six elements from `array1` then the first six elements from `array2` then the next six elements from `array1` and so one...
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a double for-loop. The second for-loop will go through 6 elements every time the first for-loop iterates. The first for-loop will use array1 and will divide its length by 6 to determine how much times it should iterate. (If length of array1 is 12, the loop should loop 2 times). There’s also a check in the second for-loop whether i is even so it creates an alternating pattern:

EDIT: you’d want the array with the larger length to be the array used in the first for-loop to ensure all elements are used in both arrays which I included utilizing the Math.max() method

```
String result = “”;
for(int i = 0; i < Math.ceil(Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)/6) ; i++) {
    for(int j = i*6; j < i*6 + 6; j++) { 
        if(i % 2 == 0 && j < array1.length) //every time i is even (to ensure alternating pattern
            result += array1[j];
        else if(j < array2.length)
            result += array2[j]; //making sure j is within length of array2
        else
            break; //j is out of bounds of both arrays, so break the loop
    }
}
textArea3.setText(result);
```

Anyone please fact check this loop if there’s mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest by converting the Arrays to some form of `Collection` first to use their functionality. Here's one possible way to go about it by converting them to an `ArrayList` first and then removing the values from the ArrayLists for appending.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupArraysTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array1 = {"A", "bunch", "of", "values", "for", "testing", "purposes."};
    String[] array2 = {"Even", "more", "values", "with", "more", "values", "than", "previous", "array", "for", "testing", "purposes."};
    
    System.out.println(groupArrays(3, array1, array2));
  }
  
  public static String groupArrays(int wordCount, String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array1));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array2));
    
    while(!list1.isEmpty() || !list2.isEmpty()) {
      for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        if(!list1.isEmpty())
          builder.append(list1.remove(0)).append(" ");
        else
          break;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        if(!list2.isEmpty())
          builder.append(list2.remove(0)).append(" ");
        else
          break;
      }
    }
    
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```